# Twitter Dropdown Doesnt Show

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns:

First Dropdown:

[image]

First Dropdown Code:

```
<select name="idx" id="masthead_search">                     
    <option value="">Library catalog</option>                           
    <option value="ti">Title</option>                           
    <option value="au">Author</option>                            
    <option value="su">Subject</option>
    <option value="nb">ISBN</option>                                                       
    <option value="se">Series</option>
    <option value="callnum">Call number</option>                                                       
</select>
```

Second Dropdown:

[image]

Second Dropdown Code:

```
 <select name="branch_group_limit" id="select_library">
     <option value="">All libraries</option>                                       
     <option value="branch:01">Main Library</option>                                            
 </select>
```

In order to change the highlight background of the option tag when hovered, I converted select and option tag to ul li tag using this jquery code.

```
/** Convert a select-option tag to ul-li tag to change its dropdown highlight color from blue to green  **/
$(document).ready(function(){

     /**masthead_search **/
     $('#masthead_search').parent().prepend('<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown"><span data-bind="label">Library catalog</span> <span class="caret"></span></button><ul id="newmasthead_search" name="masthead_search" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">');

     $('#masthead_search option').each(function(){
     $('#newmasthead_search').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" role ="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
});
     $('#newmasthead_search').append('</ul></div>');
     $('#masthead_search').remove();
     $('#newmasthead_search').attr('id', 'masthead_search');

     /**select_library **/
     $('#select_library').parent().prepend('<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown"><span data-bind="label">All libraries</span> <span class="caret"></span></button><ul id="newselect_library" name="branch_group_limit" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">');
     $('#select_library option').each(function(){
     $('#newselect_library').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" role ="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
});
     $('#newselect_library').append('</ul></div>');
     $('#select_library').remove();
     $('#newselect_library').attr('id','select_library');
});

$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

    var $target = $( event.currentTarget ); 
    $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
    .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
    .end()
    .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

    return false; 
});
```

After executing the code the dropdowns looks like this:

First Dropdown:

[image]

First Dropdown Code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span data-bind="label">Library catalog</span> 
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>

        <ul id="masthead_search" name="masthead_search" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li value="" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Library catalog</a></li>
            <li value="ti" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Title</a></li>
            <li value="au" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Author</a></li>
            <li value="su" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Subject</a></li>
            <li value="nb" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">ISBN</a></li>
            <li value="se" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Series</a></li>
            <li value="callnum" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Call number</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Second Dropdown:

[image]

Second Dropdown Code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix open">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <span data-bind="label">All libraries</span> 
       <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="select_library" name="branch_group_limit" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li value="" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">All libraries</a></li>
        <li value="branch:01" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Main Library</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But When I resize my Browser Window and click the first button, my first dropdown doesnt show. And when I click my Second Drop-down the dropdown that is shown is the dropdown which is supposedly in my First Dropdown.

First Dropdown:

[image]

Second Dropdown:

[image]

Where did I go wrong? please help me.

Comment: if you select an option from the dropdown, which `select` element gets updated?

Comment: @khakiout --> When I select a dropdown option from the second dropdown, the second dropdown gets updated.

Comment: its hard to tell the error, when you re-size the screen, to what size does the error occur?

Comment: i think the postion of the dropdowns are not proper when you resize your browser window.Try to get your textbox(that shows dropdown on click) position using offset() and set the respective dropdown list position(set top and left accordingly) exactly at the textbox position .This will always opens the dropdown list exactly where your textbox is . Hope this help !!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is not really an answer to your question, but I can't fit it into a comment and I think it needs to be said.

You really need to think carefully as to whether for the sake of changing the colour of drop down items you want to do all this. This is a pretty hefty abuse of HTML and looks like it already has (and will continue to) lead you down a rabbit hole of awkwardness and problems. What you are doing here is throwing away a `<select>` element and replacing it with a `<ul>`. You might think 'so what', it looks and works fine, and gives you a greater amount of control over styling, let me try and convince you the why you should just stick with a `<select>`.

### You're going to have a lot of fun posting that data

It looks like you are putting these drop downs in as part of a search form. This means it will be within a `<form>` element with an action to something like *`http://myawesomewebsite.com/search`*, and your search button is a submit button. When you hit submit the page will collect up all the form fields in your form and POST them to the search page. How are you planning on making the page POST your selected option? From the looks of one of the comments, it's possible you have some sort of JavaScript somewhere that is updating a hidden `<select>`? This will work, but isn't super pretty.

### Mobiles/Touchscreens play nicely with selects

You're obviously developing with mobiles/touch screen devices in mind. Great! Too many people still don't bother. Native Select elements will (depending on the specific device/browser) render a nice, scrollable list when you click on it, which is much easier for a user on a small screen to tap than a drop down list that could potentially extend beyond the bottom of the users small screen. People browsing on mobiles will expect to see their devices native list picker when they click a drop down list, don't break peoples expectations without good reason.

### Styling/positioning issues

Just like the one you are getting now. A native select list will position itself perfectly well. No hacks or even JavaScript required.

### Other things

Remember I mentioned 'abuse of HTML' earlier, if you are expecting the user to select from a list, the element that should be rendered is a `<select>`, that's how the HTML standard was defined. This also helps accessibility devices understand what your element is and what it should do with it. A drop down list rendered as a `<ul>` doesn't really make sense to a screen reader, but a `<select>` with `<option>` tags make perfect sense. I think Bootstrap does quite a good job of helping screen readers understand elements like it's specialist dropdowns, but I'm no expert on accessibility, so I'm not sure.

I don't know about you, but whenever I use a select box, I click it, hit a key on my keyboard that corresponds to the first letter of what I am after and hit enter. You can't do that with a Bootstrap dropdown (although they are keyboard accessible, so that's good). In your case this perhaps doesn't matter too much, as your options are limited, but with more options this becomes a real time saver for the power users among your user base.

Have you also noticed the fact that in the Bootstrap docs they don't even show you an example of how to use a drop down in this way? The only example they provide are based on menus with links, not replacement selects. There is probably a good reason for that.

### So, in conclusion

I'm well aware that there will always be reasons to customize things beyond their original spec, but if you can help it always try to use the elements for what they were designed for. There are plenty more pitfalls than I have mentioned here, and any future developers who take over this code will much prefer a simple select box than a convoluted, jQuery dependent solution. I'll admit that styling of select boxes has always been an issue, but from what I have seen of *this particular case*, I would recommend just sticking with selects.

However, if you still want to go with this solution then can I recommend you create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) of your problem, with **all** relevant HTML and JavaScript, so we can have a better crack at replicating your issue.

I hope this has not come off as condescending, and I am by no means saying what you are doing is wrong, as I know nothing of your exact situation, I just felt an explanation as to the potential benefits of keeping it simple might help you or future visitors to this question.